# How do I remove .x.x.x.... and .y.y.y... from headings when I do a full join of multiple dataframes that contain same column names in R?

Tags: r

file1

| Country | Name | Race | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

file2

| Country | Name | Race | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

file3

| Country | Name | Race | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

file4

| Country | Name | Race | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

The above are a some .csv data frames that I assigned to a variable called `file.list`, and then used `lapply`. The purpose was to full join every data frame into a single one, as you can see by the code below.

`file.list= c(file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, file4.csv)`

`df.list <- lapply(file.list, read.csv)`

`data <-df.list %>% reduce(full_join, by=c("Country", "Name", "Race"))`

data

| Country | Name | Race | A.x | B.x | C.x | A.y | B.y | C.y | A.x.x | B.x.x | C.x.x | A.y.y | B.y.y | C.y.y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

Although the full join works using the above code, the headers have a .x or .y added behind their names.
How can I full join such that the headers retain their original names without the .x.x... and .y.y.. behind? It should be a horizontal join retaining every single column. I find that if I add
`,suffix=c("","")`, the "A", "B" and "C" columns will merge. I've also tried `if (endsWith(colnames(data), ".x")==TRUE){` but not sure how to proceed.

Sample data

```
df_list <- list(structure(list(Country = c("Rf", "Ew"), Name = c("wef",
"eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), A = 1:2, B = 1:2, C = 1:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L)), structure(list(Country = c("Gw", "Wd"), Name = c("wef",
"eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), A = 3:4, B = 5:6, C = 7:8), row.names = c(NA,
-2L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(Country = c("Qp",
"Ew"), Name = c("wef", "eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), A = 3:4,
    B = 10:11, C = 7:8), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Desired output

```
  Country Name Race  A  B  C  A  B  C  A  B  C
1      Ew eggw   qw  2  2  2 NA NA NA  4 11  8
2      Gw  wef  wed NA NA NA  3  5  7 NA NA NA
3      Qp  wef  wed NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 10  7
4      Rf  wef  wed  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
5      Wd eggw   qw NA NA NA  4  6  8 NA NA NA
```

Comment: What happens to the values when the "columns merge"? You could also melt them and stack them.

Comment: It seemed like only the values from one dataset remained. I don't really want to stack the values together i.e into just three columns "A", "B", "C" but keep them in separate columns "A", B", "C", "A", B", "C", "A", B", "C", "A", B", "C".

Comment: Since all frames have identical column names, that _suggests_ that a join operation is not what is really needed (though it still might be, depending on the context ... through rare). Perhaps you need them row-concatenated instead, ala `bind_rows(df.list)`?

Comment: I've tried this but it just stacks the dataframes on top of one another. I would like that the "Country", "Name", "Race" columns are merged, but the "A", "B", "C" columns are not. Hence why I used ```reduce(full_join, by=c("Country", "Name", "Race"))```. The problem is that R will add suffix .x.x... and .y.y... to subsequent columns, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: You're doing it to yourself, but your own design: if a column is not a "key" to join by, then if it exists on both sides _they will be renamed_. Period. Any other tactic (in the simple act of merging) is data-lossy. The join function is not going to know which of them to keep, since it's 100% contextual. Once you join just two frames, you will have them A.x and A.y (etc) columns, what is your strategy for reducing them? Do you want to `mutate(A = coalesce(A.x, A.y))` (repeat for other columns)? Are you certain that you can discard the other non-`NA` value? Sample data would be informative.

Comment: I've added sample data. No, I don't want to discard any values if that's what you're asking. Perhaps it's possible to write a for loop or if statement to remove the suffixes from the column names? I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Your sample data has different column names in the different lists, not representative. R does not tolerate having columns with the same name; `$`- and `[`/`[[`-indexing will not work reliably (using names themselves), which means that most tidyverse functions will be restricted to the first instance of each name. Why are you trying to make a frame that R won't work well with?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but it was actually a typo. I've changed the data such that they have the same column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want the names to be duplicated, but while I don't think we can force `dplyr::*_join` to do it, we can force `base::merge` to do it.

```r
purrr::reduce(df_list, merge, by=c("Country","Name","Race"), suffix=c("",""), all=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
# Warning in merge.data.frame(out, elt, ...) :
#   column names 'A', 'B', 'C' are duplicated in the result
# Warning in merge.data.frame(out, elt, ...) :
#   column names 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C' are duplicated in the result
#   Country Name Race  A  B  C  A  B  C  A  B  C
# 1      Ew eggw   qw  2  2  2 NA NA NA  4 11  8
# 2      Gw  wef  wed NA NA NA  3  5  7 NA NA NA
# 3      Qp  wef  wed NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 10  7
# 4      Rf  wef  wed  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 5      Wd eggw   qw NA NA NA  4  6  8 NA NA NA
```

The warnings cannot be avoided, though they can be suppressed with `suppressWarnings`.

Answer (score 1):

We could rename the column names - drop the suffixes:

```
colnames(data)[ 4:ncol(data) ] <- sub("([^.]+)\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "\\1", 
                                      colnames(data)[ 4:ncol(data) ])

data
#   Country Name Race  A  B  C  A  B  C  A  B  C
# 1      Rf  wef  wed  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 2      Ew eggw   qw  2  2  2 NA NA NA  4 11  8
# 3      Gw  wef  wed NA NA NA  3  5  7 NA NA NA
# 4      Wd eggw   qw NA NA NA  4  6  8 NA NA NA
# 5      Qp  wef  wed NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 10  7
```